# Angular-Auth0 & Requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, auth0

I am trying to get the authentication of auth0 ( with my nodejs and angularjs(1.6.9) app. The backend already works so now I am trying to do the same in the frontend. I use requirejs to load all the necessary files. I already used [this](https://github.com/auth0/angular-auth0/issues/35) workaround here to fix the "auth0 is not defined" failure. Now the auth0 is defined, so angular-auth0 is supposed to work as well. Unfortunately it seems like the provider is somehow not working, it is undefined when I call the init() function. I hope sombedoy has an idea... Thanks in advance!
This is my error message:

```
 jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module timemanagement due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
    at http://localhost:3000/js/app.js:12:38
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5106:19)
    at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:4993:35)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5003:11
[...]
```

main.js

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "",

  // alias libraries paths
  paths: {
    //Frameworks
    'angular': 'vendor/angular/angular',
    'angular-route': 'vendor/angular/angular-route',
    'angular-uiroute': 'vendor/angular/angular-ui-router.min',
    'angular-resource': 'vendor/angular/angular-resource',
    'angular-de': 'vendor/angular/angular-locale_de-de',
    'auth0-variables': 'vendor/replace/auth0-variables',
    'lock': 'vendor/angular/lock.min',
    'svg-assets-cache': 'vendor/angular/svg-assets-cache',
    'angular-datepicker': 'vendor/angular/angular-datepicker',
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min',
    'bootstrap-bundle': 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min',
    'jquery-easing': 'vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min',
    'sb-admin': 'js/sb-admin.min',

    "auth0-js": "vendor/replace/auth0",
    "preauth0": "js/preauth0",
    "auth0.auth0": "vendor/angular/angular-auth0",

    //Controllers
    [....],
  },

  shim: {

    'app': ['auth0-js'],
    "auth0-js": {
      "exports": "Auth0"
    },
    "auth0.auth0":{
      'deps':["angular", "auth0-js", "preauth0"],
    },
    'angular-de': ['angular-datepicker'],
    'angular-datepicker': ['angular-uiroute'],
    'angular-uiroute': ['angular-route'],
    'angular-route': ['angular-resource'],
    'angular-resource': ['angular'],
    'angular': {
      'deps':['auth0-variables'],
      'exports': 'angular'
    },
    'auth0-variables': ['sb-admin',],
    'sb-admin': ['jquery', 'jquery-easing', 'bootstrap-bundle',]
  },

  // kick start application
  deps: ['app']

});
```

preauth0.js

```
define(function (require) {
    auth0 = require('auth0-js'); 
});
```

app.js

```
define(['angular', 'angular-route', 'angular-uiroute', 'angular-resource',
    'angular-datepicker', 'auth0-js', 'auth0.auth0'], function () {
        var app = angular.module("timemanagement", ['ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'ngResource',
            '720kb.datepicker', 'auth0.auth0']);



        app.config(['$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$provide',
            '$stateProvider', 'angularAuth0Provider', function ($routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider,
                $controllerProvider, $provide, $stateProvider, $resource, angularAuth0Provider) {

                angularAuth0Provider.init({
                    clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
                    domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
                    responseType: 'token id_token',
                    audience: 'https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/userinfo',
                    redirectUri: AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
                    scope: 'openid'
                });
```

Comment: add `'$resource'` before `'angularAuth0Provider'` in your dependencies array

Comment: Thank you!! my mistake, didn't see that.